# Relationships between three subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let, $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space over $\mathbb R$ and $ W_1,W_2,W_3$ be subspaces of $V$. Which of the following is true?

1. If $ W_1+W_2+W_3=V$ then
   $$\mathrm{span}(W_1\cup W_2) \cup \mathrm{span}(W_2\cup W_3) \cup \mathrm{span}(W_3\cup W_1) = V.$$
2. If $W_1 \cap W_2 =\{0\}$ and $W_1 \cap W_3 =\{0\}$ then $W_1 \cap (W_2+W_3)=\{0\}$.
3. If $W_1+W_2=W_1+W_3$ then $W_2=W_3$
4. If $V\neq W_1$ then $\mathrm{span}(V-W_1)=V$.

My attempt: Take, $V=\mathbb R^3$ and $W_1=\{(x,y,z):\ y=0,z=0\}$,  $W_2=\{(x,y,z):\ x=0,z=0\}$ and $W_3=\{(x,y,z):\ x=0,y=0\}$. Then option 1 is discarded.

Take $V=\mathbb R^2$ and $W_1=\{(x,y):\ y=x\}$, $W_2=\{(x,y):\ x=0\}$ and $W_3=\{(x,y):\ y=0\}$. Then option 2 is discarded.

Take $V=\mathbb R^2$ and $W_1=V$, $W_2=\{(x,y):\ x=0\}$ and $W_3=\{(x,y):\ y=0\}$. Clearly option 3 is discarded.

So option 4 is right. But I cannot prove it. Please help to prove this

Comment: You seem to have a good understanding of the subject matter. I'm slightly curious about the definition of $V-W_1$ in option 4 (I can think of a number of formulations), and your identification of $V - W_1$, (could it include vectors with nonzero $x$ coordinate?), but under the formulations that I think are most probable, you definitely understand this stuff.

Comment: Your examples for the first three are great, but the fourth one is not. You say $V - W_1 = \{(x, y, z) : x = 0\}$, but, for example, $(1, 1, 1) \in V - W_1$, since it doesn't satisfy the definition of $W_1$ (i.e. its $y$ and $z$ coordinates are non-zero). Have another think about it.

Comment: For option 4 I think in this manner. Clearly, W_1 is a subspace of dimension 1 and dimension of V is 3. Clearly V-W cannot contain elements from the set {(x, y, z) :x=0}. So it cant be whole R^3

Comment: @DebprasadKundu $V-W$ does not contain vectors of this form, but $\mathrm{Span}(V-W)$ does.

Comment: For option $4$, the set $V-W_1$ is the complement of the $x-$axis in $\mathbb{R}^3$ which clearly contains three linearly independent vectors that span all of $\mathbb{R}^3$. It's much more than just the $yz$ plane

Comment: I understand my mistake.

Comment: So, option 4 is right. Please provide the proof of option 4

Answer (score 1):

Here is a proof for option 4: if $V \neq W_1$, then $V - W_1 \neq \emptyset$. Let $u \in V - W_1$.

We wish to show that $v \in V \implies v \in \operatorname{span}(V - W_1)$. Note that, if $v \in V - W_1$, then $v \in \operatorname{span}(V - W_1)$ trivially. So, we really only need to worry about $v \in W_1$.

Suppose $v \in W_1$, and let us suppose for the sake of contradiction that $v + u \in W_1$. Then $u = (v + u) - v$, the difference of two vectors in $W_1$. Since $W_1$ is a subspace, this makes $u \in W_1$, against assumption. Thus, $v + u \in V - W_1$.

Similarly, we have $v - u \in V - W_1$, for otherwise $u = v - (v - u) \in W_1$ against assumption. Now we can see that
$$v = \frac{1}{2}(v + u) + \frac{1}{2}(v - u) \in \operatorname{span}(V - W_1),$$
completing the proof.